# Stuck on reversing TripleDES in .NET

Tags: .net, cryptography, reverse-engineering, tripledes

I'm stuck on a target and I'm wondering to know is it possible to reverse this part of code, the goal is deal with 'nodeData' to get 'True' condition in 'result'.
As i'm not familiar on this type of cryptography so I cannot understand this part of code. BTW I thought that the 'serialNumber' is key and 'iV' is could be IV I can't figure it out this is a decryption routine or not, is it possible to generate correct key to perform true for the result?

```
    Dim serialNumber As Byte() = New Byte() {&H2, &H4E, &HA0, &HC5, &HFD, &HE0, &H99, &HF6, &H9D, &HAD, &H7A, &H2F, &H16, &HB, &HA2, &HA7,
    &HDC, &H23, &H9F, &H3F, &HE6, &H28, &HC4, &H5D, &H36, &H76, &H88, &HC3, &H86, &HE6, &H72, &HD7,
    &H5E, &HF3, &H30, &H3F, &HD2, &H2B, &H7F, &H16, &H9C, &H9B, &H4E, &HC4, &HF2, &H46, &HDC, &H2
    }
    Dim iV As Byte() = New Byte() {&H36, &H76, &H88, &HC3, &H86, &HE6, &H72, &HD7}
    Dim provider As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider With { _
        .KeySize = &HC0, _
        .BlockSize = &H40, _
        .Padding = PaddingMode.None _
    }
    Dim destinationArray As Byte() = New Byte(&H18 - 1) {}
    Array.Copy(serialNumber, destinationArray, &H18)
    Dim buffer4 As Byte() = New Byte(8 - 1) {}
    Array.Copy(serialNumber, &H18, buffer4, 0, 8)
    Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = provider.CreateDecryptor(destinationArray, iV)

    Dim nodeData As Byte() = New Byte() {&HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA,
        &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA,
        &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA
    }

    Dim arrays As Byte() = Nothing
    Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(nodeData)
    Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
        Dim list As List(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte)()
        While True
            Dim expr_91 As Integer = cryptoStream.ReadByte()
            Dim num As Integer = expr_91
            If expr_91 = -1 Then
                Exit While
            End If
            list.Add(CByte(num))
        End While
        arrays = list.ToArray()
    End Using
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Dim volumeSerialNumber As Integer = &HC45D3676
    Dim bytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(volumeSerialNumber)
    Dim array2 As Byte() = New Byte() {arrays(22), arrays(23), arrays(24), arrays(25)}
    If array2.Length = 4 AndAlso bytes.Length = 4 Then
        result = (bytes(0) = array2(0) AndAlso bytes(1) = array2(1) AndAlso bytes(2) = array2(2) AndAlso bytes(3) = array2(3))
    End If
```

Comment: There is actually [an SE site that is dedicated to reverse engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com), why not ask there?

Comment: So `Dim nodeData As Byte() = New Byte() { &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &HAA, &H3A, 9, &H6F, &HD0, &H11, &H30, &H47, &H83, &HD3, &HE2, &H73, &H9F, 1, &HDE, &HC0, &H44, &HBB, &H66, &H18, &H70, &H54, &H43, &HAB, &HBA, &H30, 6, &H67, &HED, &H27, &H56, 120, 12 }` gives true. Now what?

Comment: Most important part of my question is cryptography

Comment: @zespri great, could you please explain me how did u get this and how can I get such values....

Comment: I encrypted the data you are trying to arrive to with the same key you are using for decryption. It's very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve from your question.

Comment: @zespri, I want exactly what you get, that was my question, could u please provide me source code if it's possible?!

Comment: Sina, I'm glad you got an answer, but please note that these kind of questions are considered too broad. Please ask a concise question next time, this reads as request for somebody else to do the work for you. Sometimes you get lucky, but usually you are downvoted into oblivion. Closing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, not fluent with VB. In C# encryption code could look like this:

```
        byte[] serial = { 
            2, 0x4e, 160, 0xc5, 0xfd, 0xe0, 0x99, 0xf6, 0x9d, 0xad, 0x7a, 0x2f, 0x16, 11, 0xa2, 0xa7, 
            220, 0x23, 0x9f, 0x3f, 230, 40, 0xc4, 0x5d, 0x36, 0x76, 0x88, 0xc3, 0x86, 230, 0x72, 0xd7, 
            0x5e, 0xf3, 0x30, 0x3f, 210, 0x2b, 0x7f, 0x16, 0x9c, 0x9b, 0x4e, 0xc4, 0xf2, 70, 220, 2
         };
        byte[] iv = { 0x36, 0x76, 0x88, 0xc3, 0x86, 230, 0x72, 0xd7 };
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
        {
            KeySize = 0xc0,
            BlockSize = 0x40,
            Padding = PaddingMode.None
        };
        byte[] destinationArray = new byte[0x18];
        Array.Copy(serial, destinationArray, 0x18);


        ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateDecryptor(destinationArray, iv);
        byte[] data = { 
            170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 
            170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 
            170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170
         };

        byte[] decryptedData;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
        using (CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
            while (true)
            {
                int current = stream2.ReadByte();
                if (current == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                list.Add((byte)current);
            }
            decryptedData = list.ToArray();
        }

        int num = -1000524170;
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);

        decryptedData[0x16] = bytes[0];
        decryptedData[0x17] = bytes[1];
        decryptedData[0x18] = bytes[2];
        decryptedData[0x19] = bytes[3];

        ICryptoTransform transform2 = provider.CreateEncryptor(destinationArray, iv);
        byte[] bla = transform2.TransformFinalBlock(decryptedData, 0, decryptedData.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < bla.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(bla[i]);
            Console.Write(",");
            if (i % 16 == 15)
                Console.WriteLine();
        }
```